# How does this function concatenate work with first order functions?

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml, higher-order-functions

```
let concat (l : string list) : string = fold_right (fun a x -> a ^ x) l ""
```

so to go through it, I see that

- let concat takes a list with strings, and returns a string.
- fold right takes 3 parameters,

  - 1 the first being a function that concatenates two strings, it takes a and x, and then concatenates them using ^.
  - 2 the second argument is the list,
  - 3 and finally the third is the accumulator that gets each pass added to it.

BUT, how does the `func a x` know that a is the first element of the list, and x is the second.

And when it passes through again, how does it know that a is the third element of the list, and x is the fourth, and so forth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `accumulator` is the first argument, `a`, to the `fold function`, and `x` is `set to each element` of the list in turn as the `fold` walks over it.

The return value of the `fold function` is the `new value` of the `accumulator`.

The initial value of the `accumulator` is the `empty string`, so the result of the first concatenation, which becomes the `new accumulator`, is the same value as the `first element` of the list.

Then the `next element` is concatenated to that, and so on until the end of the list is reached, at which point the `fold` returns `final value of the accumulator`, the fully concatenated string.

Comment: Just a small comment: for `List.fold_right` the accumulator is the *second* argument of the folded function. For `^` it doesn't matter so much. For `List.fold_left` the accumulator is the first argument.